# Empezar lectura de un txt con PHP iniciando desde la linea 2

Tags: php, txt, fopen

Hola estoy generando la lectura de un archivo txt el cual tiene una estructura como la siguiente

```
Cabecera
122121215656565
686846846846846
489498498498498
19894984949444
PiePagina
```

Me interesa recuperar la linea 2 `122121215656565`

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
//Abriendo el archivo
    $arc = fopen('archivos/' . $nombre, "r");
//Obteniendo una linea completa del archivo txt
    $linea = fgets($arc);
//Cerrando el archivo
    fclose($arc);
```

Con este código me devuelve `Cabecera`, como podría indicarle a PHP que únicamente me recupere la línea 2, de antemano muchas gracias y espero haber sido claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas una solución podría ser el ir iterando hasta llegar a la sección del archivo que requieras.

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");
$i = 0;
$tmp = "";
while(!feof($file))
  {
      $tmp = fgets($file);
      $i++;
      if($i == 2)
          break
  }
echo $tmp;
fclose($file);
```

Saludos...

Comment: Saludos funciono perfecto muchas gracias, eres un genio, de verdad gracias

Answer (score 1):

Con la función file, puedes acceder al contenido del fichero como si fuera un array (cada linea será un elemento del array):

```
$file = file('file.txt');
$linea = $file[1];
```